# paste0 broken after updating R

Tags: r, csv, web-scraping

I have been running a very simple code in R for scraping a csv and saving it, and I am pretty sure it was working all fine until I updated R this morning.
My workspace clearly does contain folder 'reports/google'([image: workspace]), but I am getting a destination error. A code written as such:

```
download.file('https://www.file.csv', 
           destfile = paste0('reports/google/google_', today_date, '_report.csv'))
```

produces an 'Error in download.file("https://www.file.csv",  : 
  cannot open destfile 'reports/google/google_2020-06-07_report.csv', reason 'No such file or directory'

This occurs despite the folders existing and csv being online. Is there a package which I missed installing during update for paste0? I would have thought it updated with R itself as it is a base suite package. Any advice would be welcome.

Edit: if I only paste0 as

```
destfile = paste0('google_', today_date, '_report.csv'))
```

it works just fine. But I would really like to save it to subfolder.

Comment: since this works `paste0('google_', today_date, '_report.csv')` it means nothing is wrong with `paste0`. Recheck if `reports/google` is the path in your working directory or do you need to explicitly mention the complete path?

Comment: You're using a relative path, right? My first guess would be to check the working directory (`getwd()`).

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough, restarting my PC resolved the issue, without any change in code, for future reference of anyone finding this problem after updates.